# Will an iPhone XR purchased in India work with US service providers?

Tags: iphone

I am planning to buy an iPhone XR in India, and take it to the US. Will it work on most GSM providers in USA? I compared the specification on Apple's iPhone webpage, and it looks like only a couple of bands are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would. An iPhone purchased in India has support for GSM frequency bands in USA. It would function similar to an unlocked iPhone bought in USA.